# Why is DownOrNot and JustPing reporting that my website is down?

Tags: web-server, ping, web, host

I was pinging my site with DownOrNot and it is reporting that my website is [down from all locations](http://www.downornot.com/qweop).

Then I pinged it with JustPing and it is reporting that my website is [also down from all locations](http://just-ping.com/index.php?vh=qweop.com&c=don_ab_just-ping&s=ping%21&vtt=1315849142&vhost=_&c=don_ab_just-ping).

However, `http://qweop.com` definitely works fine for me. I tried visiting the site through a couple of other proxies and all of them are finding `http://qweop.com` online.

What's causing the issue here?

Why is DownOrNot and JustPing reporting that my website is down?

<sub>Update: Note: this is a test site. I no longer own `qweop.com`.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as per uSlackr.

It appears that currently both of your name servers are not answering..

```
qweop.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns01.000webhost.com.
qweop.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns02.000webhost.com.
;; Received 108 bytes from 192.42.93.30#53(g.gtld-servers.net) in 83 ms

;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`
```

It probably works for you, since the DNS cache you are using has the answers and doesn't have to go back to the root for answers.

Comment: Could you check if it is working now? =D Btw how do I clear my DNS cache?

Comment: It appears to be working now.  Clearing the dns cache can be tricky.  Your local dns cache is relatively easy to clear. but it can also be cached at any intermediary caches (your company, your isp, etc..) and clearing those caches can be harder (in case of company), and really hard in case of ISP.  To clear your local cache on windows you would do ipconfig /flushdns from a command prompt). if you need another OS let let me know. IF you have access to dig a `dig +trace qweop.com` would show you everything

Comment: @Pacerier all depends on your OS.  Windows doesn't come with dig (AFAIK) only nslookup. It might be installed depending upon your version of linux, but in ubuntu it can be found in the dnsutils package. It is standard in OSX.

Comment: ic. how do I do a `Dig` on Windows Vista ?

Comment: First you would need to install a copy of dig. I have no idea what a good/safe version would be as I don't use windows. Sorry

Answer (score 6):

The "How Do we know" page for DownorNot implies there is a DNS issue.  The status for Just ping also says it cannot resolve the hostname.  I am unable to resolve the hostname. How is your DNS handled?

Comment: What do you mean by "how is your DNS handled" ? I point them to ns01.000webhost.com. and ns02.000webhost.com.

Answer (score 2):

Your firewall is probably blocking ICMP traffic which is not allowing the ping to go through.

Comment: The OP was saying that other sites said his site was down, not from his own connection

Comment: and besides I do not have a firewall installed.